# CURL on list of links to save only specific links along with specific response

Tags: linux, bash, url, curl, sed

Hi All i have list of links, through curl I am getting their response by using this command
`curl -K file.txt`.

I am saving response to file.

But the problem is I am getting rough response(collectively all curl request result in one file),
I want to filter the response in two possible ways.

**1 -** End result in file should be organized like this URL against each response or maybe if other possible organized way.
e.g.

**Heading**
http://192.168.0.1

**Response**
(includes all responded html)

**2 -** Once first part is done, i want to keep only those urls and response which have specfic keywords.
e.g
i want only "helloworld" in urls response to stay in final result file.
if there is no particular keyword in response against any link from list remove those links and their result from file.

[image: list of urls]

Comment: Loop on your url list and call curl on each.  You can then examine the return status, and output from each and print it in an output file, with the format you want.  For the keywords, look into `grep`.  You should read [ask] and [mcve], as this question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is assuming that `file.txt` exist.

It will test the existence of `HelloWorld` in the response.

The `If` statements had been written on 3 lines for readability.

The `responses.txt` will contain the result.

An intermediary file is used to store each http response in turn: `/var/tmp/response-tmp.txt`

Give a try to this:

```
regex="HelloWorld"
rm -f responses.txt 2>/dev/null
for url in $(sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*url[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*//gIp' file.txt); do
  curl -w "http_code %{http_code}" -Ns --url "${url}" > /var/tmp/response-tmp.txt 2>/dev/null
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
    if tail -1 /var/tmp/response-tmp.txt 2>/dev/null | grep -aq "http_code 2[0-9][0-9]$" 2>/dev/null ; then 
      if grep -aq "${regex}" /var/tmp/response-tmp.txt 2>/dev/null ; then
        printf "Heading %s\nResponse " "${url}"
        head -c -13 response-tmp.txt
      fi
    fi
  fi
done >> responses.txt
```

Comment: thanks Man, worked like charm, stay blessed. :)